# php protobuf uint64 is converted to negative number

Tags: php, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have this proto definition

```
message Product {
    uint64 id = 1;
    uint64 order_id = 2;
}
```

then build the response in PHP

```
(new Product())
->setId(3)
->setOrderId(3875412541)
```

what I get then is

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "order_id": -419554755
}
```

the order id in this example is 10 characters long. Starting from 11 characters I get

```
13 INTERNAL: Failed to parse server response
```

it only works if the order_id is 8 characters long

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "order_id": 38754125
}
```

Comment: Drive-by-comment see https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10335

Comment: thanks @DazWilkin I already read that, but they suggest using string instead of uint64, which I don't think it's a good fix to be honest with you